# How to keep a copy of software downloaded from software center in linux mint

Tags: linux, linux-mint

I am upgrading to linux mint 14 buy clearing the hard disk and installing the OS. Can anyone tell me how to keep a backup copy of software that i downloaded from the software center? So that when i install mint 14 I dont have to download those software again from software center

Comment: What Satish said about your packages being in /var/cache/apt/archives is correct, however which OS are you trying to grab software you've already downloaded from? Are you trying to for instance grab the software packages from your mint 13 install and store them elsewhere for when you do your new mint 14 install? That will not work as the packages will all be meant for mint 13.

Answer (score 0):

It should be available somewhere in `/var/cache`

```
/var/cache/software-center/
```

OR

```
/var/cache/apt/archives
```